# json serialization of a list of objects of a custom class

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, class, serialization

I have a song class, which holds the attributes to a song, and it is a custom class. I also have a list of songs in a list called track list. When I try to json.dump the list, I get an error that says :

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Song' is not JSON serializable
```

How would I go about converting this list of songs to json?

Here is the additional relevant code that returns the error:

```
class Song:
def __init__(self, sname, sartist, coverart, albname, albartist, spotid):
    self.sname = sname
    self.sartist = sartist
    self.coverart = coverart
    self.albname = albname
    self.albartist = albartist
    self.spotid = spotid

tracklist = createDict(tracks) ##creates the list of songs, works fine
jsontracks = json.dumps(tracklist)
pp.pprint(jsontracks)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to post a sample of your data?  Also, you will need to indent 'def __init__...'.

Comment: This is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#json.dump). See the description of the `default` parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've solved this by adding an `encode()` method to the class:

```
def encode(self):
    return self.__dict__
```

and adding some arguments to json.dumps:

```
jsontracks = json.dumps(tracklist, default=lambda o: o.encode(), indent=4)
```

This will "crawl" down your class tree (if you have any child classes) and encode every object as a json list/object automatically. This should work with just about any class and is fast to type. You may also want to control which class parameters get encoded with something like:

```
def encode(self):
    return {'name': self.name,
            'code': self.code,
            'amount': self.amount,
            'minimum': self.minimum,
            'maximum': self.maximum}
```

or a little bit faster to edit (if you're lazy like me):

```
def encode(self):
    encoded_items = ['name', 'code', 'batch_size', 'cost',
                     'unit', 'ingredients', 'nutrients']
    return {k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if k in encoded_items}
```

full code:

```
import json


class Song:
    def __init__(self, sname, sartist, coverart, albname, albartist, spotid):
        self.sname = sname
        self.sartist = sartist
        self.coverart = coverart
        self.albname = albname
        self.albartist = albartist
        self.spotid = spotid

    def encode(self):
        return self.__dict__


tracklist = [
    Song('Imagine', 'John Lennon', None, None, None, None),
    Song('Hey Jude', 'The Beatles', None, None, None, None),
    Song('(I Can\'t Get No) Satisfaction', 'The Rolling Stones', None, None, None, None),
]

jsontracks = json.dumps(tracklist, default=lambda o: o.encode(), indent=4)
print(jsontracks)
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "sname": "Imagine",
        "sartist": "John Lennon",
        "coverart": null,
        "albname": null,
        "albartist": null,
        "spotid": null
    },
    {
        "sname": "Hey Jude",
        "sartist": "The Beatles",
        "coverart": null,
        "albname": null,
        "albartist": null,
        "spotid": null
    },
    {
        "sname": "(I Can't Get No) Satisfaction",
        "sartist": "The Rolling Stones",
        "coverart": null,
        "albname": null,
        "albartist": null,
        "spotid": null
    }
]
```

Comment: This not work with static attributes